# After updating to Enterprise Library 6: Transient Fault Handling I am getting a System.Security.VerificationException

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, windows-vista, enterprise-library-6

After updating to Enterprise Library 6: Transient Fault Handling I am getting a System.Security.VerificationException when my console application attempts to start up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research I came across [this similar issue](http://entlib.codeplex.com/workitem/33761) on the CodePlex site for the Patterns and Practices group related to the Enterprise Library.

There seems to be a known issue at release time:

> If you are using the Transient Fault Handling Application Block, you should ensure that you are using version 4.0.30319.18003 or later of mscorlib.dll, otherwise you may see a VerificationException exception at run time. For more information, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2748646.

The solution to the problem seems to indicate that this is an issue with the mscorlib version that is currently in use and there is a hotfix that will resolve the issue.

There is another KB, [2748645](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2748645), for Windows 7, Windows 7 SP1, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2008 SP2, and Windows Vista SP2: